# What is the best practice on storing lots of sockets?

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, redis, erlang

For testing purposes I want to create a socket server which will contain 10+ million concurrent socket connections spread over X number of ec2 instance on AWS (still deciding on either node.js with JXCore, Java, or Erlang). These sockets will be sending messages randomly to one other socket every 10 seconds. I am just having trouble understanding how I can store and read these sockets effectively.

The two options I can see are to store the socket objects in something like a map in the application itself, or store the sockets in a fast database such as Redis. The problem with having sockets stored in a data structure inside of the application is will it be able to scale, be robust, and how will the read performance be when millions of sockets need to find one another. And If I store them in something like a database such as redis there must be a network call every time because Socket A needs to know where Socket B is located to send the message. This I fear will bring down performance considerably.

I was wondering what the best practices are for scalable socket servers as I can't find anything on the internet which answer this question. Every socket server I find online simple broadcasts to every other socket instead of having specific sockets and only contain something like 10 sockets.

Comment: You need to investigate non-blocking IO solutions; nothing out there is going to handle the number of socket connections you want.

Comment: Non-blocking solutions?  You need to investigate server farms.

Comment: He didn't say what X is for his ec2 instances but I'll bet throwing enough at it to handle 10mil sockets is probably not the solution he wants.

Comment: I have run tests using a single 4-core 12GB server (with tweaks to the OS) and using node.js for the server with 36 clients (virtual, 512mb ram lubuntu 1-core) and was able to get 750k concurrent sockets on a single server. I plan on using 25 aws ec2 instances for the testing of 10 million. The problem was the test was only on one server and not multiple. I first thought Vert.x would be great but  I read it can't share data over instances yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this application to be distributed across a number of nodes there need to be a way to at least determine destination node. If it may be a pure function of source and current packet, no central storage is required, which is the best possible solution.

In the rest of the cases central storage is inevitable but some optimizations may be applied to reduce access to it. Local sockets can be easily stored in a local map (ets or mnesia in erlang, shared singleton map in other languages) and checked first. Source may be told to cache destination address so the packet would contain all the necessary information. Or that destination cache could be stored on the source socket node to not depend on client behavior. This cache may be used for routing and only if the route operation was unsuccessful the central storage may be accessed.

The may be some other optimizations which depend on what's available in your case.